# How to write filenames based on a dask dataframe column?

Tags: amazon-s3, dask

I have a dask dataframe that I would like to save to s3. Each row in the dataframe as a "timestamp" column. I would like to partition the paths in s3 based on the dates in that timestamp column, so the output in s3 looks like this:

```
s3://....BUCKET_NAME/data/date=2019-01-01/part1.json.gz
s3://....BUCKET_NAME/data/date=2019-01-01/part2.json.gz
...
...
s3://....BUCKET_NAME/data/date=2019-05-01/part1.json.gz
```

Is this possible in dask? I can only find the name_function in the output that expects an integer as an input, and setting the column as an index doesnt add the index as part of the output filenames.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easy to achieve, as long as you are happy to save it as parquet, using `partition_on`. You should rename your folder from `data` to `data.parquet` if you want to read with dask.

```py
df.to_parquet("s3://BUCKET_NAME/data.parquet/", partition_on=["timestamp"])
```

Comment: (the name of the output folder should not matter)

Comment: yeah i know parquet does it (since fastparquet and pyarrow support it). I am looking to do it in json format).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the only or optimal way but you should be able to do it with [groupby-apply](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html#Groupby-Apply), as in:

`df.groupby('timestamp').apply(write_partition)`

where `write_partition` is a function that takes a Pandas dataframe for a single timestamp and writes it to S3. Make sure you check the docs of [apply](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply) as there are some gotchas (providing `meta`, full shuffling if the groupby column is not in the index, function called once per partition-group pair instead of once per group).

Comment: yeah I had thought of this, but it would be quite expensive i believe?

would it be possible to do it by repartition and then passing the files argument?  Something like this: 

```
df = df.set_index("timestamp")
date_index = df.index.unique().compute()
df = df.repartition(npartitions=len(date_index))
 files = [f"{s3_output_path}date={d}.json.gz" for d in date_index]
df.to_json(files)

```